# css properties difference between firefox 3.1 and 3.5 how to fixe this?

Tags: css, firefox

I have a web page using css and it's run ok in firefox 3.5 but not in firefox 3.1 and chrome. Anyone have an ideal for this problem, please show me the way to fix this. Is there any way to hack css in firefox 3.1 and firefox 3.5

Comment: I think you forgot to say what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

after a hour google I've found this one:
body:nth-of-type(1) p{
   color: #333333;
}
this script will run correctly in safari and chrome. I wonder how to hack css in firefox 3.1 and firefox 3.5